# MVC deployment in IIS 6 in win server 2003

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-6, web-deployment

Please help me how to deploy mvc3 application in IIS 6. I don't know how to set first page (start page in mvc) application. Which page I want to set first and hpw to set, I copied my full application from local machine to remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Look here: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/04/options-for-deploying-aspnet-mvc-to-iis-6/. You're not really setting a "default page" in MVC since everything is routed to controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access any of your action method/ page and see whether the MVC routing works for you.

To make the extensionless url work in IIS6, You need to enable wildcard mapping. Make sure you uncheck the "Verify file exist" option. Wildcard mapping brings some performance problems though. check the [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) by Phil explaining it.